# Deserialization with binaryformatter

Tags: c#, serialization, .net-assembly, binaryformatter

I have a program that serializes an object and sends it over a network:

```
TcpClient client = new TcpClient();
client.ReceiveTimeout = 10000;
client.SendTimeout = 10000;
IPEndPoint serverEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 8888);
client.Connect(serverEndPoint);

BinaryFormatter binaryformatter = new BinaryFormatter();

NetworkStream networkStream = client.GetStream();
if (networkStream.CanWrite)
{
    binaryformatter.Serialize(networkStream, kort);
}
```

And on the other side I receive and deserialize the code as such:

```
TcpClient tcpClient = (TcpClient)client;
tcpClient.SendTimeout = 10000;
tcpClient.ReceiveTimeout = 10000;
NetworkStream clientStream = tcpClient.GetStream();
try
{
    if (clientStream.CanRead)
    {
        BinaryFormatter binaryformatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        binaryformatter.Binder = new AllowAllAssemblyVersionsDeserializationBinder();

        Kort tempkort = (Kort)binaryformatter.Deserialize(clientStream);
        SetImage(tempkort);
    }
}
catch (SerializationException e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Failed to deserialize. Reason: " + e.Message);
    throw;
}
finally
{
    clientStream.Close();
    tcpClient.Close();
}
```

But when I deserialized I got this error about an assembly missing:

> "An unhandled exception of type `System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException` occurred in Server.exe Additional information: Unable to find assembly 'Client, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.

which I solved with this:

```
sealed class AllowAllAssemblyVersionsDeserializationBinder : SerializationBinder
{
    public override Type BindToType(string assemblyName, string typeName)
    {     
        String currentAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().FullName;

        // In this case we are always using the current assembly
        typeName = "Server.Kort";
        assemblyName = currentAssembly;

        // Get the type using the typeName and assemblyName
        Type typeToDeserialize = Type.GetType(String.Format("{0}, {1}",
            typeName, assemblyName));

        return typeToDeserialize;
    }
}
```

But now that I try to do it, I keep getting an error that says:

> "Object of type `Server.Kort` cannot be converted to type `Server.Kort+kortvalör`."

And I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: "But when i deserialized i got an error about an assembly missing or something" post that error.

Comment: The error i got was "An unhandled exception of type 'System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException' occurred in Server.exe

Additional information: Unable to find assembly 'Client, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The class `Kort` on the sending side must contain an instance of a nested type (perhaps an `enum`?) called `kortvalör`.  And, since `BinaryFormatter` serializes public & private *fields* instead of properties, the nested type could be completely invisible to the outside world, but still get serialized.

For instance, I was able to reproduce your exception `"Object of type Server.Kort cannot be converted to type Server.Kort+kortvalör"` using your binder with the following class:

```
[Serializable]
public class Kort
{
    // Private enum that is invisible to the outside world.
    enum kortvalör 
    {
        Zero,
        One,
        Two,
        Three
    }

    kortvalör valör = kortvalör.Three;

    public int Value
    {
        get
        {
            return (int)valör;
        }
        set
        {
            // Check to make sure the incoming value is in a valid range.
            var newvalör = (kortvalör)value;
            if (Enum.IsDefined(typeof(kortvalör), newvalör))
                valör = newvalör;
            else
                valör = default(kortvalör);
        }
    }
}
```

When deserializing the class above, your binder will be called twice, once with the `typeName` for `Kort` -- and then once with the typename `"MyClientNamespace.Kort+kortvalör"`.  Since your binder ignores the incoming `typeName` and returns `typeof(Kort)`, this fails.

You have a few options to solve this problem:

1. Extract your class `Kort` into a shared DLL and link it with both the sending and receiving applications.  Then the problem goes away.
2. Create duplicates of all types referenced by `Kort` in both the sending and receiving applications -- including private nested types -- and remap the type names appropriately inside a smarter version of your `SerializationBinder`.  The article [Advanced Binary Serialization: Deserializing an Object Into a Different Type Than the One It was Serialized Into](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20178/Draw-with-Mouse#AdvancedBinarySerialization%3aDeserializinganObjectIntoaDifferentTypeThantheOneItwasSerializedInto9) has an example of how to do it.
3. Consider using a different serialization format that serializes *properties* rather than private fields.  [BSON](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeToBson.htm) is one option.  [Protobuf-net](https://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/) is another.

Comment: Thank you so much, I did the first step and it works perfectly.