# "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" in binary deserializing

Tags: c#, sqlite, serialization, nullreferenceexception, binaryformatter

I am Serializing a class object and storing in sqlite database as BLOB from a C# application.

Function used for serializing: `public static byte[] ObjectToByteArray (AnalyzeSubstring obj)`

And on other application, fetching the blob database and converting blob database in to the object by deserializing. 
function for deserializing is :`public static AnalyzeSubstring ByteArrayToObject (byte[] arrBytes)`

```
public static byte[] ObjectToByteArray (AnalyzeSubstring obj)
              {
              if ( obj == null )
                  return null;
              BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter ();
              //bf.AssemblyFormat = System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.FormatterAssemblyStyle.Simple;
              MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream ();
              bf.Serialize (ms, obj);
              return ms.ToArray ();
              }

          public static AnalyzeSubstring ByteArrayToObject (byte[] arrBytes)
              {
              MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream ();
              BinaryFormatter binForm = new BinaryFormatter ();
              memStream.Write (arrBytes, 0, arrBytes.Length);
              memStream.Seek (0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
              AnalyzeSubstring obj = (AnalyzeSubstring) binForm.Deserialize (memStream);
              return obj;
              }
```

Issue:In line while deserializing `AnalyzeSubstring obj = (AnalyzeSubstring) binForm.Deserialize (memStream);`.

It fails with error

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object .

However if we do both operation in same application only, then this work properly.

Please help

Comment: how have you declared AnalyzeSubstring. It suggests that this has not been instanciated correctly when seperating the Method. Dont forget you will have to reference it through the project dependencies.

Comment: I have used the same class AnalyzeSubstring in both applications.how to reference it through project dependencies?

Comment: in VS you create a solution. You then create 1:N Projects in that solution. your First project will have the method in a Class. The second project then  needs to make a reference to the first project to gain access to it's properties and methods. Right mouse click on the second projects references and select add reference.

Comment: ok.. lemme try that..:)

Comment: @bilpor: Is there any way, in which I dont require to add reference. and make two projects independent . From my application I simply want to fetch the blob data from database.

Comment: you'd have to write the method twice. Once in each project, but the way to go is to perhaps create a 'Common' dll with the methods in. You create this in a solution. When you compile it it becomes a single Dll in its own right. Then in your other projects you reference the dll in the same way. You point to the compiled dll.

Comment: You need to either extract `AnalyzeSubstring` to a shared DLL or create a `SerializationBinder` that maps between them.  See [Deserialization with binaryformatter](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30198132/3744182) for three possible options.  See also [How to get BinaryFormatter to deserialize in a different application](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7534790/3744182).